# Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

```html
package com.nissan.common.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan
@Slf4j
public class SwaggerConfig {

  @Value("${swagger.api.controller.basepackage}")
  private String basePackage;



  @Bean
  public Docket swaggerApi() {
    log.info("Swagger Api loaded");
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(basePackage))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
  }

  
}
```

2022-07-05 17:24:53.527  WARN 6444 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springfox/documentation/spi/service/ResourceGroupingStrategy.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2022-07-05 17:24:53.536  INFO 6444 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-05 17:24:53.559 ERROR 6444 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springfox/documentation/spi/service/ResourceGroupingStrategy.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be nice if you would not just throw your code and error message at us, but also write a few sentences about what you want to achieve and what you tried so far. Also, please make use of the formatting possibilities we provide also for your error logs.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I found the fix. I've given it below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the Spring Boot based projects, it's enough to add a single springfox-boot-starter dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```